# Making Editor.js works in Remix

Tags: remix.run, editorjs

I'm trying to integrate [Editor.js](https://editorjs.io/) into a [Remix](https://remix.run) app.

I have tried different options (with ou without `react-editor-js`) but I always end up with compile errors:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at /home/.../project/node_modules/@editorjs/link/dist/link.umd.js:2:6471
```

or

```
ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at /home/.../project/node_modules/@editorjs/checklist/dist/checklist.umd.js:2:1525
```

I have also tried to setup the editor with no plugin at least to have a working base, but i'm also ending with a console error in the browser:

```
Warning: Prop `id` did not match. Server: "react-editor-js-18c6d074c06" Client: "react-editor-js-18c6d074d5a"
```

```
Editor.js is not ready because of Error: element with ID «react-editor-js-18c6d074d5a» is missing. Pass correct holder's ID.
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: element with ID «react-editor-js-18c6d074d5a» is missing. Pass correct holder's ID.
```

By using the following component:

```js
import { createReactEditorJS } from "react-editor-js"

const ReactEditorJS = createReactEditorJS()

export default function EditorInput() {
    return (
        <ReactEditorJS
            defaultValue={{
                time: 1635603431943,
                blocks: [
                    {
                        id: "sheNwCUP5A",
                        type: "header",
                        data: {
                            text: "Editor.js",
                            level: 2,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        id: "12iM3lqzcm",
                        type: "paragraph",
                        data: {
                            text: "Hey. Meet the new Editor. On this page you can see it in action — try to edit this text.",
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }}
            tools={{}}
        />
    )
}
```

If anyone as a working example, it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend wrapping the Editor inside `ClientOnly` (from remix-utils).

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].